# single root of a cubic function

Tags: equation-solving

As it can be shown that the function **f(x)=3x^3-9x+1** has a single root in the interval abierto (0,1). 
Try to solve using Newton Raphson method, but that is more than a demonstration calculation

Answer (score 3):

```
f[x_] = 3 x^3 - 9 x + 1;

Solve[{f[x] == 0, 0 < x < 1}, x] // N
```

{{x -> 0.111574}}

```
Reduce[{f[x] == 0, 0 < x < 1}, x] // ToRules // N
```

{x -> 0.111574}

```
FindRoot[f[x], {x, .5}]
```

{x -> 0.111574}

Newton-Raphson

```
x -> FixedPoint[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, .5]
```

x -> 0.111574

Answer (score 3):

Try the following form of `FindRoot`:

```
FindRoot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "Brent"]
```

This form with the `Method -> "Brent"` gives very good performance and stable results even in pathological cases (when two roots of the cubic equation are very close to each other but only one of them lies in the interval `{0, 1}`).

Comment: @mfvonh "+1"? You forgot to actually upvote. :)

Comment: details, details

Comment: What kind of details do you need?

Comment: Oh I was just making light of the fact that I missed the all-important "detail" (upvoting, now fixed :D)